# RSpec Timecop failures around Date appear to be timezone related

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time, rspec, momentjs, timecop

We have some tests (specs) that are failing around Date/Time. Guessing it's a UTC issue but not sure why these specs passed last time project was touched (~8-months ago)!?!

*#spec/features/comments/creation_spec.rb*

```
feature 'Comment creation', type: :feature, js: true do
  include CommentsPageHelpers
  ...
  let!(:current_date) { Date.parse('2017-01-03') }
  ...

  background do
    Timecop.freeze(current_date)
    ...
  end

  after do
    Timecop.return
  end

  shared_examples 'added comment' do |position:, text:|
    scenario 'adds single comment' do
        ...
        expect(page).to have_text 'January 3rd, 2017'
      end
    end
  end
```

View (Angular template) *#app/views/templates/comment.html.slim*

```
.comment
  ...
  {{ comment.createdAt | moment: 'MMMM Do, YYYY' }}
```

*#RSpec Failure*

```
Comment creation for image behaves like added comment adds single comment
     Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_text 'January 3rd, 2017'
       expected to find text "January 3rd, 2017" in "John Snow First comment message January 2nd, 2017Remove"
     Shared Example Group: "added comment" called from ./spec/features/comments/creation_spec.rb:76
     # ./spec/features/comments/creation_spec.rb:42:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/features/comments/creation_spec.rb:39:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: This is a known issue: https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop/issues/100

Comment: hmm…seems insane not to be able to reliably test Date in a 15-year-old framework?!? workaround?

Comment: You really shouldn't be using Date in Rails anyway as its not time zone safe. Try `Time.parse('2017-01-03').to_date` or other workarounds mentioned in the ticket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the `let!` line to the two lines below seems to have fixed things. Don't know what else it might break or if it will break for devs in other timezones?!?

```
Time.zone = 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'
let!(:current_date) { Time.parse('2017-01-03').in_time_zone }
```